# How to change css property by angularjs, DOM nodes is disallowed error

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change the css property by angularjs when hovering

Here is my code:

```
$scope.showButtonGroup = () ->
        buttonTools = document.getElementsByClassName('widget-formwidget-topright-actions')
        angular.element(buttonTools).css('display': 'block')
```

But the console shows me the error that: Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression:

Could someone help me on that? thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/bsTbZ86WAY4). What AngularJS means is to avoid the returning of DOM. Thus return `undefined` or `null` in your CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take advantage of `ngStyle` directive, where you assign scope variable to change element's style

**controller**

```
$scope.changeDisplay = function(value) {
    $scope.displayProperty = value;
}
```

**markup**

```
<div ng-style="{display: displayProperty}" ng-mouseenter="changeDisplay('block')" ng-mouseleave="changeDisplay('none')"></div>
```

Comment: not a problem, angular has directives also for hovering - `ngMouseenter` and `ngMouseleave` where you can define which function it should trigger and in that function change the style

Comment: yes, I know, what I am trying to say is, the function (showButtonGroup) is a hovering function, for showing button group when hovering, so why should I use ng-style?

Comment: check the edited answer... `ngStyle` is the correct way of manipulating css styles via angular, that's why you should use it